# C unsigned char arithmetic operation does not works as expected

Tags: c++, type-conversion, arithmetic-expressions

Here is the my snippet of code;

```
Npp8u * imageHost;  
typedef unsigned char Npp8u;
...
for (int i=0;i<nHeight;++i)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<nWidth;++j)
        {
            printf("number_befre : %u\n",imageHost[i*nWidth+j] );
            imageHost[i*nWidth+j] = imageHost[i*nWidth+j]-Npp8u(min);
            imageHost[i*nWidth+j] = imageHost[i*nWidth+j]/(max-min);
            printf("number : %u\n",imageHost[i*nWidth+j] );
        }
    }
...
```

Some values are assigned to `max = 202` and `min = 0` and extracted from imageHost. I rectified it with debugging but the content of the `imageHost` is 0 for whole elements. What can I do more to make these statements work with reasonable precision? Is this about the restriction of the data type that I used?

Comment: `Nppu(min)` is not valid C. Are you compiling this as C++?

Comment: sorry code is lacking and I edited

Comment: this is cuda code actually but the host side

Comment: it is written at the explanation below of the code

Comment: What's the type of `imageHost[]` elements? What are their values? Are `max` and `min` equal to 202 and 0 respectively?

Comment: You've said that imageHost[] is zero after this calculation but you haven't explained what values you are expecting instead. Give an example of what "number_befre : ????" is, and what you expect to see for "number : ????"

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze is is Npp8u and values are respectively

Comment: @john since I get the min and max from imageHost I am expecting to see some decimal numbers that are normalized between unit length. I am simply calculating (imageHost-min / max-min)

Comment: But imageHost is `Npp8u`. If you want decimal numbers you need an array of `double` (or `float`). So yes it's a restriction of the data type you are using.

Comment: But I need to have a Npp8u at the end. While I am searching a see the method of scaling factors. Can be a solution ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @Erogol That is impossible. Your calculation results in a number between 0.0 and 1.0, but the only numbers that Npp8u can have are integers. So everything is going to be either 0 or 1, nothing in between. You need to rethink your problem.

Comment: @Erogol The link you posted is a possibility. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to normalize numbers to between 0.0 and 1.0. But the data type you have chosen is not suitable for that as it can only handle integers. You need code something like this

```
typedef unsigned char Npp8u;
Npp8u * imageHost = ...;
vector<float> normalizedImageHost(nHeight*nWidth)
...
for (int i=0;i<nHeight;++i)
{
    for (int j=0;j<nWidth;++j)
    {
        normalizedImageHost[i*nWidth+j] = (float)(imageHost[i*nWidth+j] - min)/
            (max - min);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to keep `Npp8u` but use a scaling factor. For instance we could multiply all the value by the maximum Npp8u value which is 255.

```
typedef unsigned char Npp8u;
Npp8u * imageHost = ...;
...
for (int i=0;i<nHeight;++i)
{
    for (int j=0;j<nWidth;++j)
    {
        imageHost[i*nWidth+j] = (Npp8u)((255.0*(imageHost[i*nWidth+j] - min))/
            (max - min));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF** `imageHost[i*nWidth+j]` is less than `max-min` then

```
imageHost[i*nWidth+j]/(max-min)
```

will be zero. Because `unsigned char` can not store real values between `[0.0 .. 1.0]`

For better accuracy you should use floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: imageHost is in same type and max and min values are extracted from.

Comment: it is not possible to get 0 for all the values algebraically because of the nature of the calculation that I perform but it might be 0 due to the data type that I used and I am expecting to hear the solution not the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: please write comments for such things

Answer (score 0):

i guess your problem is imageHost memory. check its memory.(post previous lines if it possible)
or do this and debug program for first line variable value (breakpoint on second line):

```
Npp8u  x=Npp8u(min);
imageHost[i*nWidth+j] = imageHost[i*nWidth+j]-x;
```

you get memory for imageHost (do this):

```
Npp8u ** imageHost=new *Npp8u*[nHeight];
for(int i=0;i<nHeight;i++)
     imageHost[i]=new Npp8u[nWidth];
```